# Duplicate template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

I need to dynamically create a copy of a template in Meteor. The copy should have the same handlebars content, but a different set of helpers, methods and event handlers. How can I achieve that?

I've tried:

```
Template.copy = function() {
    return Template.original.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

and it displays the right html, but the resulting template is not reactive. On the other hand, when I do

```
Template.copy = function() {
    return Meteor.render(Template.original.apply(this, arguments));
}
```

the result of `render` is a `DocumentFragment` object that I don't know how to properly convert to string or attach to DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [this package](https://github.com/apendua/meteor-copy-template) should work fine. Basically speaking, to achieve what you want, you need to get access to your tempalte's `raw_func` and then call `Template.__define__(name, raw_func)` with a different name. It is possible to do that, if you hack the original `Template.__define__`, as it is done [here](https://github.com/apendua/meteor-copy-template/blob/master/copy_template.js#L5-L8)). However, you'll need a package to do all the hacking in the right moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look at the new Meteor UI parts. All of the code here is about to change quite a bit.

I think you should be able to do stuff like

```
Template.copy = Template.extend(original, {});
```

There's more details on it if you check out this [meteor-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/gHSSlyxifec) discussion or this [faq](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview). There is a preview release up you could test with

```
meteor --release template-engine-preview-3
```